# Alter Column Type from Char to Varchar in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with primary key 'username' and it's 'Char' , and I have to change it to varchar.
There is a way to do that without lose the data? 
cause it's primary key and cascading all the other tables.

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name  -<-- Your Table Name
 ALTER COLUMN username  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I wrote that there are other tables the link to this one. I can't run this SQL Code cause I get error:
The object 'X' is dependent on column 'username'. 
The object 'X' is dependent on column 'username'. 
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN username failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: Well in that case you cannot change the datatype, you need to drop the foreign key constraints, free the column of any constraints and then change the data type and then create them constraints again, But you will need to change data types of all the columns in all ther tables that references this column.

Answer (score 6):

If this column is your **primary key** on a table that's referenced by many other tables, it'll be a bit more involved:

1. Drop all the foreign key constraints in all the other tables that reference that primary key
2. Drop the primary key constraint on your table
3. Change the datatype of your column (`ALTER TABLE .... ALTER COLUMN ..... VARCHAR(n) NOT NULL`)
4. Re-create the primary key constraint
5. Change the datatype of **every single foreign key column** in every single referencing table to that same datatype
6. Re-establish all the foreign key relationships from all the other tables to the newly created `VARCHAR(n)` primary key column

Comment: Anyone have generic boiler plate that does this dance for an arbitrary set of tables constraints and datatypes?  Sounds like a pain to do manually.